# adding a constructor argument to migration script in truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I got a pretty simple ERC-20 contract here:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract SonnyCoin is ERC20 {
      constructor(uint256 initialValue) public ERC20("SonnyCoin", "SCN") {
             _mint(msg.sender, initialValue);
      }
}
```

And then my migration code for the contract is the following:

```
const SonnyCoin = artifacts.require("SonnyCoin");
const web3 = require("web3");
const initialValue = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SonnyCoin(initialValue))
  //I've also tried deployer.deploy(SonnyCoin({value: initialValue}))
}
```

I just want to add the parameter to make it a dynamic issuance contract but I'm not sure what I'm missing, I looked at the truffle documentation regarding migration scripts and their parameters here and it appears that I'm doing what the [documentation dictates](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html#deployerdeploycontract-args-options) but I'm evidently missing a key piece. Any help as far as adding a parameter to the constructor function is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a syntactic mistake on my part contrary to the syntax you may think it is to pass arguments to a contract construstor like this

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SonnyCoin(arg1))
}
```

You'll actually want to pass arguments to the constructor like so:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SonnyCoin, arg1)
}
```

source: [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/cannot-read-property-address-of-undefined-deploying-erc20-example-from-documentation/4820/3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=deploy#deploy), how to pass the parameters for a constructor.

```
myContract.deploy({
   data: '0x12345...',
   arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
```

Under "arguments" section, we can pass params.